# How is the tab chosen when opening a link from an external location?

Tags: safari, skype, url, links

I have Safari open with 111 tabs open.
I clicked on a URL that a friend sent me on Skype.
Safari opened the link in a random tab that wasn't selected, and was neither the first or the last one on the left or right.
The URL that I clicked replaced this tab's content, it was not a new tab.

How was this random tab selected out of the 111 tabs, to be the recipient of the URL I clicked?

Comment: The window an external link will open on was the first window that opened when you last restored the session - either at relaunch or reboot. They don't always reopen in the same order. Took me a while to work that one out.

Comment: it's not what the situation was in this case, the tab had been unlooked at for a few sessions I think

Comment: "first window that opened" - you don't have to have looked at it since. It decides the Window order at launch, & it doesn't always appear to be the same order.

Comment: What do you mean? The tabs are always in the order I left them when I quit Safari and reopen it (thank god!)

Comment: Window, not tab - or do you have all those tabs in a single window?? The windows, if you have many, are reopened in the same locations, but not necessarily the same numbered order.

Comment: Yes, all the tabs are in one single window, and the reopened tab was it seems random considering their position and frequency or use

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a random tab but the current active tab. But with 111 tabs open, I'm surprised the app's memory is not hosed so much that it's making mistakes now. That count seems a bit high. Try to reduce the tab count--after restarting Safari--and check the behavior then.

Comment: Thanks! This is how I use tabs... since 2002 :P I don't understand bookmarks, they don't work at all for me, it's like burying something out of sight and never remembering about it ever again... :)

Comment: I get it, but Safari eats RAM for each tab. So that many will put a strain on your system in some way. Also I do suggest that you make bookmarks your friend, or, if you just want something to go back to later, use the Reading List--akin to an Instapaper for later reading.

Comment: I know about the strain, I am okay with it. I'm a very visual person and remember webpages by how they look sometimes rather than by what they're called. I also constantly work on more than 50 projects so closing and reopening tabs would take too much time...